# Remote switch to activate smart outlet

Tags: smart-home

I have quite a few smart outlets that I run through a wink hub and use Alexa to activate. It all works great. However I would like to have a switch on the wall for some of them also. Is there a way to do this. I am open to IFTTT. I just didn’t know of a switch that existed just for sending a signal. Seemed like they all needed to actually be wired to something. Was hoping for something like the pico remotes but have it work with generic z-wave stuff

Comment: Just to be clear, you are looking for wall mounted, Z-wave standalone switch?

Comment: do you want a button or switch? a switch can "lie" about the state if you can control it externally...

Answer (score 2):

You can simply make your own device for this using NodeMCU, Solid State Relay (5V), 5V Power Supply. NodeMCU can connect to your home wifi. You can link this setup with Google Home or Alexa too. for more information visit: https://webservice.lk OR https://sinric.com

Comment: Hi Lahiru, can you add some information about how one would be going about creating such a device. Currently this is more a less just consisting of two (useful) links.

Comment: Hi, You have more than enough information in mentioned to web sites. I cannot place them here since it has lots of contents with step by step guidelines. Anyway if you can state here, where are you stuk ? or which part you cant understand ? I will be able to resolve your problem.